# How to retrieve data from relation?

Tags: php

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment extends Model
    {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }


   }
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Now my question is how i can access all comments that belong to post with commented username 
Thank you in advance

Comment: having only username you'd be able only to get all comments to ALL posts owned by given user, for this you can use hasManyThrough relation

Comment: @zakius.thank you for the comment.can you post your answer

Comment: Try this `user::with('post.comment') -> get()`

Comment: @mdamia.thank you.is it possible to access in single query.i need to display Post content with author name and all comments belongs to that post with username

Comment: I will post something as answer, give it a shot.

Comment: @mdamia.ok thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will return all posts with comments, and posts with authors for the selected user.

```
$data = User::with('post.comment') 
        -> with('post.author') 
        -> Where('id',$user_id) 
        -> first();
```

This will fetch posts with authors and post with comments with users who made the comments.
Assuming your models are set up this way,

```
Post belongs to an Author,   
Author has many Post,  
Post has many Comment  
Comment belongs to a Post  
Comment belongs to a User  
User has many Comment.   

$posts = Post::with('author') -> with('comment.user') -> get();
```

Comment: my requirement is  .i need to display Post with post auther name and along with comments that belong to that post with commented username.if you see my table structure.i am storing commented user id means forign key

Comment: @madamia.i get collection object correctly.but at the end i get error like Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2025: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user() \

Comment: @vision check that `user` method is defined

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is simple to solve with hasmanythrough relationship (check http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a query for comment relationships, like the following:

```
$post_id = 7;
$username = 'username';

$comments = Comment::where('post_id', $post_id)->whereHas('user', function($q) use($username) {
    $q->where('username', $username);
})->get();
```